# How to prevent a function from being optimized

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I am optimizing the entire code, yet I dont want a certain function from being optimized, say for debugging purposes. Is there a way to do  it on gcc 3.4+ compiler?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Easiest way, place the function in its own compilation unit, compile that one without optimization flags.

Recent gcc versions (4.4+ I think) have an attribute to control optimization per functions, use

```
__attribute__((optimize(0)))
```

on the function to disable optimizations

Comment: Compilers generally __do not__ gurantee that debug/release version of binaries have the same ABI or padding etc.... Thus it is not safe (in the general case) to assume that this will work (though it may work for your compiler).

Comment: Do you have an example?   I know the microsoft uses a different C runtime for debug executables, but that the cross-module function call and structure alignment interoperability is guaranteed.  And gcc generates 100% compatible output in all regimes, as far as I know.

Obviously things like structure alignment and ABIs are outside the realm of the language standard, so compilers don't *have* to honor them when generating debug output.  But that strikes me as more a pedantic point than a practical one.

Comment: OP asked about gcc and gcc does not have nonsense like different "debug" and "release" ABIs.

Comment: Does this still work? I can't get this to work anymore for my app.