# Prevent specific functions or classes from being removed through optimization in native code in release build version

Tags: android, c++, cmake

On trying to build APK for 64bit devices, the compiler seems to do extra optimizations on native CPP code which is breaking some core functionalities of my app. When I build with the flag `#set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} -O0")` it works fine.

I'm trying to figure out

1. If I can prevent the compiler from doing the certain optimizations which break the functionalities.

or

2. If I can understand why compiler is seeing my code as un-used code via something like [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#troubleshoot-resource-shrink)

In the quest of achieving the first option, I tried using `pragma` pre-processor directive according to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12695212/4099634)
- by using the line `#pragma optimize("", off)` before the required function, 
- also by using the line `#pragma GCC optimize ("O0")` at the beginning of the file.

However, I see the same set of symbols in the shared library, and it seems to have no effect on the build process. It also seems that NDK r18 already has GCC version 4.9, which should mean pragma directive should work properly, but I can't figure out why it is failing.

I also tried using [attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1494002/4099634) 
`__attribute__((optimize("O0")))`. But couldn't see the symbol get added to my shared library after this as well.

So I want to ask if either `pragma` or `attribute(optimize)` are still supported and if I am doing something wrong here. Or if there is a better way to solve this problem or to understand how to prevent compiler from optimizing the required functions.

Comment: _"the compiler is doing extra optimizations that break core functionality of my app"_ is a red flag. Does your app introspect its own binary? Otherwise this is either a serious compiler bug or a serious bug in your code...

Comment: no i am not introspecting the binary after the build, but we have seen this happen even on the java side for which we use proguard, so looking for similar on native side